# ACL list to deny even networks

Tags: cisco

I wonder if you can help me. I am trying to set up an ACL. I have a network - 172.16.1.160/27 and I need to deny hosts with an even number in the last octet. What wild mask would I use to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a wildcard mask that has an even number in the last octet. The address in the ACL should be a `deny` on an even address.

For example, to deny even numbered hosts:

```
ip access-list Deny_Even_Hosts
 deny ip 172.16.1.160 0.0.0.30 any
 permit ip any any
!
```

To deny odd numbered hosts:

```
ip access-list Deny_Odd_Hosts
 deny ip 172.16.1.161 0.0.0.30 any
 permit ip any any
!
```

By setting the least significant bit to zero, you are saying that this bit must match that bit in the address.

Comment: Much obliged for pointing out that ignorance on my part.

Comment: @AndrewB, I just had a call this morning with an engineer who couldn't figure out why an ACL had wildcard masks of `0.0.127.254`. He thought it must be contiguous, but I explained that he was only permitting odd numbered addresses, then it made sense to him. Normally, if you are doing this, you are doing networking wrong. IPv6 doesn't have this ability since it on uses the VLSM/CIDR notation, and all bits are contiguous.